# Can I type assert a slice of interface values?

Tags: interface, type-conversion, go, type-assertion

I am trying to type assert from a `[]Node`, to `[]Symbol`. In my code, `Symbol` implements the `Node` interface.

Here is some surrounding code:

```
 43 func applyLambda(args []Node, env Env) Node {
 44     if len(args) > 2 {
 45         panic("invalid argument count")
 46     }
 47     fixed, rest := parseFormals(args.([]Symbol))
 48     return Func{
 49         Body: args[1],
 50         FixedVarNames: fixed,
 51         RestVarName: rest,
 52     }
 53 }
```

Here's the error I get:

```
./builtins.go:47: invalid type assertion: args.([]Symbol) (non-interface type []Node on left)
```

I'm sure there's a good reason for this. What's the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In saying `x.(T)` variable `x` should be of interface type, because only for variables of type interface dynamic type is not fixed. And while `Node` is an interface, `[]Node` is not. A slice is a distinct, non-interface type. So it just doesn't make sense to assume a slice of interface values is an interface too.

Type `Node` has a clear definition in your code and thus is an interface. You have specified the list of methods for it. Type `[]Node` isn't like that. What methods does it define?

I understand where your are coming from with this. It may be a useful shortcut, but just doesn't make sense. It's kind of like expecting `syms.Method()` to work when `syms`'s type is `[]Symbol` and `Method` is for `Symbol`.

Replacing line 47 with this code does what you want:

```
symbols := make([]Symbol, len(args))
for i, arg := range args { symbols[i] = arg.(Symbol) }
fixed, rest := parseFormals(symbols)
```

Comment: I do not agree with your sentense "So it just doesn't make sense to assume a slice of interface values is an interface too". Conversions are conversions - interfaces are interfaces. They are separate concepts (at least in my mind). Go authors could have decided to support conversions from `[]Node` to `[]Symbol`, but they didn't because it is too costly and such conversions aren't a common programming pattern. Theoretically, any conversion that does not entail a contradiction nor an issue makes sense - but language designers need to choose which conversions to put in the language.

Comment: I can't say for sure what Go authors think about this matter, but I still think my assumption is true. You are right that this conversion is too costly, but I don't think that's the reason for making that illegal. As I said, in Go slice is a type. You can say `type Nodes []Node`. Is `Nodes` an interface type? No. So I see that's the reason we can't assert variables of type `[]Node`. Would you like to do this discussion on the golang-nuts mailing list?

Comment: @Atom: The question doesn't ask about conversions; it asks about type assertions

Answer (score 6):

Go does not allow this. You need to convert `Node` to `Symbol` individually.

The reason why it isn't allowed is that `[]Node` and `[]Symbol` have different representations, so the conversion would need to allocate memory for `[]Symbol`.