# Go Golang : Type assertion on customized type

Tags: types, interface, go, type-conversion

http://play.golang.org/p/icQO_bAZNE

I am practicing sort using heap but

```
  prog.go:85: type bucket is not an expression
  prog.go:105: cannot use heap.Pop(bucket[i].([]IntArr)) (type interface {}) as type int in assignment: need type assertion
  [process exited with non-zero status]
```

I am getting those errors and can't figure out how to type assert properly

The problem is from the lines:

```
  heap.Push(bucket[x].([]IntArr), elem)

  arr[index] = heap.Pop(bucket[i].([]IntArr))
```

Because I want to use heap structure in order to extract values from each bucket

And each bucket is `[]IntArr`

And `IntArr` is `[]int` like the following

```
type IntArr []int
type bucket [10]IntArr
```

I have been trying many ways over the weekend and can't figure out, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use heap package you should implement heap.Interface for your type (in this case, for your IntArr type). You can find example here: http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#pkg-examples

Then you can do things like

```
heap.Push(bucket[x], elem)
```

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/F0J4qXdmzD  I try this but still not working... How would you change my code to work?

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/i7O8HB6ez8 - use this as a starting point. Debug your algorithm, your sort doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

From [go spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression
>
> `x.(T)`
>
> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.
>   The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.

`bucket[x]` is not an expression of an interface type, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478641/can-i-type-assert-a-slice-of-interface-values).

Comment: Yes you are right, but I can't figure out how to make bucket[x] an interface type with type assertion and I am failing to do this. Could you briefly explain how you would change my code?

Comment: @MaynardEPSILON I think that you should consider what [@kluyg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/91570/kluyg) said about implementing the `heap.Interface` instead of any type assertion.