# golang 2 slice types with 1 field

Tags: struct, go, union

In light of the fact that golang does not support unions, what is the best way to achieve:

```
type foo struct {
    words []string
    nums []int
}
```

such that only `words` or `nums` can be used at once. One thing I've tried is:

```
type foo struct {
    values []interface{}
}
```

but I prefer something that restricts the types to the two mentioned or something with pointers.

Comment: Isn't it already discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/q/21553398/6309? Not to mention http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/1424z09454/go-nuts-what-is-the-best-practice-for-unions-in-go

Comment: The problem is that I want the slice's values to all be the same type. I don't see to how enforce that from these links other than checking every value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `foo` package to hide the implementation. For example,

```
package foo

const (
    typeWords = iota + 1
    typeNums
)

type Foo struct {
    fooType byte
    words   []string
    nums    []int
}

func NewWords(words []string) *Foo {
    return &Foo{fooType: typeWords, words: words}
}

func NewNums(nums []int) *Foo {
    return &Foo{fooType: typeNums, nums: nums}
}

func (f *Foo) Words() []string {
    if f.fooType != typeWords {
        return nil
    }
    return f.words
}

func (f *Foo) Nums() []int {
    if f.fooType != typeNums {
        return nil
    }
    return f.nums
}
```

ADDENDUM:

Since we are hiding the implementation of package `foo`, we can implement it another way. For example, we could adopt [twinj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1448032/twinj)'s suggestion and use an interface. To ensure some degree of generality, let's add another `[]string` type `Phrases`. The value types are used to distinguish between the two `[]string` types.

```
package foo

type (
    valueWords   []string
    valuePhrases []string
    valueNums    []int
)

type Foo struct {
    value interface{}
}

func NewWords(words []string) *Foo {
    return &Foo{value: valueWords(words)}
}

func (f *Foo) Words() []string {
    value, ok := f.value.(valueWords)
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }
    return value
}

func NewPhrases(phrases []string) *Foo {
    return &Foo{value: valuePhrases(phrases)}
}

func (f *Foo) Phrases() []string {
    value, ok := f.value.(valuePhrases)
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }
    return value
}

func NewNums(nums []int) *Foo {
    return &Foo{value: valueNums(nums)}
}

func (f *Foo) Nums() []int {
    value, ok := f.value.(valueNums)
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }
    return value
}
```

Comment: small note: would seem to be just as functional with "typeWords = iota" instead of "typeWords = iota + 1"

Comment: @lf215: No it's not. I didn't want the zero value for the type to be valid. It's only valid if it's created explicitly in the `foo` package. For example, `var f foo.Foo` would have zero for the `fooType`; the `fooType` is undefined.

Comment: Nice; I would also add a method to return the type using a type switch and also a method to check if a Foo has been initialized since value is private.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use an interface and type assertion.

```
type Foo struct {
    values interface{}
}

func (o *Foo) Words() []string {
    if v, ok := o.values.([]string); ok {
        return v 
    }
    return nil
}

func (o *Foo) Nums() []int {
     if v, ok := o.values.([]int); ok {
        return v
    }
    return nil
}
```

Check out the Go playground example: [GoPlay](http://play.golang.org/p/27D770MZ6l)

Note:

1. Foo cannot be an interface type (type Foo []interface{} or type Foo interface{}) but can be a struct which contains an interface type.
2. You also cannot assert []interface{} to another slice type as an []interface{} is a type in its own right. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478641/can-i-type-assert-a-slice-of-interface-values)